# How to add two buttons to a div with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm attempting to add two buttons to a div, one beneath the other. The first button accepts a number and the second will be used to toggle lines on and off.

Only the second button I append is created. How do I create two buttons in the same div?

Here is a [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2djysb6o/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<body>
<div id=options>
<script>

(function(){
  var form = d3.select("#options")
      .append("form")
      .html("Enter a number:")

  form.append("input")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("name", "num")

  form.append("input")
      .attr("type", "button")
      .attr("value", "Add")
      .attr("onclick", "printNum(num.value)")

  form.html("Show/hide lines:")    
      .append("input")
      .attr("type", "button")
      .attr("name", "toggle")
      .attr("value", "Toggle")
      .attr("onclick", "togglePressed()");
})();

function printNum(num){
  alert("You entered " + num + "!");
}

function togglePressed(){
  alert("You pressed the toggle button!");
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the html of the form *after* trying to append things to the form. So in other words, the append functions work, and then you destroy everything and swap it out for what is in your `.html` function.

either move this block to *before* the append calls:

```
form.html("Show/hide lines:")    
  .append("input")
  .attr("type", "button")
  .attr("name", "toggle")
  .attr("value", "Toggle")
  .attr("onclick", "togglePressed()");
```

or alternately, don't use the `.html` function.

reference: "setting the inner HTML content will replace any existing child elements" https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#html

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kueuLLr4/